# How to put random.randint into a list

Tags: python, list, arraylist, random, chr

I'm having trouble trying to put a random.randint into my list and making it work so far I have this:

```
strings = [str(chr(random.randint(65, 90))) % x for x in range(0, int(uppercase) + 1)]
        for string in strings:
            print(string)
```

I can get it to work without random.randint with just adding text but I can not get it to work for random.randint

Also I want to see if I can turn the list into a single sentence "useful for my purpose"

Comment: Hi! what should be your desired output? and what is the 'uppercase' variable?

Comment: Are you importing random. What error is being thrown?

Comment: you're trying to use `%` on a `str` -- not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
strings = []
for x in range(0, int(uppercase) + 1):
    strings.append(str(chr(random.randint(65, 90))))
```

For creating a single sentence:

```
result = ""
for element in strings:
    result += str(element)
print(result)
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem?

Comment: The code he listed doesn't work and causes an error. The code I have listed resolves the conflict and allows the user to convert the random number `str(chr(random.randint(65, 90)))` into `str` based on the iteration performed on `range(0, int(uppercase) + 1)`. Further, the user requested a single a sentence printing which I have listed as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should start your range from 1 to avoid zero division error
you can use this example instead:

```
strings = [str(random.randint(65, 90) % x) for x in range(1, int(uppercase))]
for string in strings:
    print(string)
```

The output is like this:

```
0
0
2
0
```

In this case uppercase is "5"